# using associative arrays as translators

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I've been wondering for a while, is it efficient (in a manner of resources and speed) to use associative arrays as translators?

For example, let's say we have a calculator class which receives an operation object and then calls a function to execute, `run()`. In order to check what operation the user is trying to use, we can either do a `if()` or `switch()` and then set the right operation or, we can do something like `new $operations[$operation]` where `$operation` represents a string like `+` or `-` and the `$operations` array values for these keys (correspondingly) are `Addition` and `Subtraction`. By doing that we can instantiate the operation we need without writing a long `switch()` or `if()` statement.

Code demonstration:

### Calculator.php

```
class Calculator {

    protected $result = null,
              $operands = [],
              $operation;


    public function setOperands() {
        $this->operands = func_get_args();
    }

    public function setOperation(Operation $operation)
    {
        $this->$operation = $operation;
    }

    public function calculate() {

        foreach($this->operands as $num) {

            if( ! is_number($num))
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException;

            $this->result = $this->operation->run($num, $this->result);
        }

    }

}
```

### Operation.php

```
interface Operation {
    public function run($num, $current);
}
```

### Addition.php

```
class Addition implements Operation{

    public function run($num, $current) {
        return $num + $current;
    }

}
```

### Subtraction.php

```
class Subtraction implements Operation {

    public function run($num, $current) {
        return $num - $current;
    }

}
```

Now, when we use these classes:

```
$calculator = new Calculator();

// input from user
$operation = "+";


$calculator->setOperands(1,2,3);

/**
 * One way to set the operation
 */

// set the operation
switch($operation) {

    case '+':
        $calculator->setOperation(new Addition);
        break;
    case '-':
        $calculator->setOpration(new Subtraction());
        break;
    // and so on..

}

$calculator->calculate();

/**
 * Second way to set the operation
 */

$operations = ['+' => 'Addition', '-' => 'Subtraction']; // can add more

$calculator->setOperation(new $operations[$operation]);

$calculator->calculate();
```

Is the **second** way of setting the operation is efficient (in a manner of resources and speed)?

Comment: ok where is the problem you are facing?

Comment: if your taking into account lower caps then no

Comment: Your explanation is bit confusing. You're begining with calculator as example and ending with translation of acronyms. How they are related?

Comment: @hindmost Sorry for that. I didn't really face an actual code issue. I'm trying to figure out whether it's efficient to use associative arrays instead of big `if()` or `switch()` statements. You can leave the acronyms part and just focus on the calculator.

Comment: @kfirba Without any code it is very hard to understand your problem

Comment: @hindmost I see. I will edit my post in few minutes after I've written a code example. Thanks for your willingness to help.

Comment: @hindmost The post has been edited.

Comment: I don't think the second way is more efficient in terms of resources and speed. But it obviously better than the first one in terms of _maintainability_

Comment: @hindmost I agree about the resources. But, are you sure about the speed? BTW, what would you recommend to use? I find the second way easier to use and as you said, much easier to maintain and extend

Comment: @kfirba I think I'm sure). AFAIK `switch` operator is not much slower than array element accessing. Anyway difference is minor. So you should not concern about speed in this case

Answer (score 0):

Lets think I have an array

```
$acronyms = ['AFAIK' => 'As far as I know', 'MVP' => 'Most valuable player'];
```

And the String to get Translated

```
$string = "AFAIK I do the MVP";
```

Now I will do this

```
echo strtr($string,$acronyms);
```

Now My Output will be

```
As far as I know I do the Most valuable player
```

Comment: Thanks for that but that was not what I really meant. I was asking if it's efficient using associative arrays for translation instead of `switch()` or `if()` statement